# Calling the same functions from multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I have written a program in C that will start 2 threads (UDP/TCP). Each thread will send packets.

I am sending packets every 5 seconds in both threads. Both threads will call the same functions as shown below:

No global variables are being modified, and only the parameters are being used inside the shared functions.

Since no shared variables are being updated, it is safe for both threads to call the same function? Would this result in any undefined behavior?

```
//create message
int getMsg(char * msg, int size)
{
    char strMsg[size];
    sprintf(strMsg, "%d", 10);
    strcat(msg, strMsg);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;        
}

// tcp
void send1()
{
    while(1)
    {
        // create message to send
        char str[100];
        int rVal;
        rVal = getMsg(str, 100);
        if(rVal != EXIT_FAILURE)
        {
            // send packet
            sendto(fd, strlen(str), 0, dest, sizeof(*dest));
        }
        usleep(5000000); 
    }
}

// udp
void send2()
{
    while(1)
    {
        // create message to send
        char msg[200];
        int rVal;
        rVal = getMsg(msg, 200);
        if(rVal != EXIT_FAILURE)
        {
            // send packet
            sendto(fd, strlen(str), 0, dest, sizeof(*dest));
        }
        usleep(5000000); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything will be fine unless you are changing data which another thread is going to be accessing.

Comment: A problem unrelated to the mutithreading is that you pass pointers to uninitialized arrays to `getMsg()` and that function tries to append to those uninitialized strings.

Comment: You are appending a fixed string so there's no reason to allocate `str` or print to it in `getMsg`

Answer (score 3):

yes, it is safe to call common function through multiple threads as long as the function don’t incorporate use of global or static variables. each thread creates a seperate copy of called funtion onto their respective call stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior can happen if the function is not thread safe.
For example if it uses some `global data`, has some `static variables` inside
or receives as a parameter pointer so some data the same for each thread.

So usage of static variables should be removed, usage of global and common data should be wrapped by some synchronization mechanism like Criticalsections.

Answering your question your `getMsg` function is thead safe.